# Android How to keep my AsyncTask from failing

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hey,
So I am new to Android and tried to implement a class that has a lot of lines of code by making a wrapper class that makes it a new thread. Within this activity it calls a bunch of other classes and while my UI thread loads fine, I think my calculation thread is timing out or having some other form of failure because when I run it I get the ANR dialogue. To see how far in it is failing I put in a println in one of my inner classes and it seems to be failing very early on. Is there a time limit on AsyncTasks? or am I maybe doing something wrong that is causing it to crash? any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no time limit. But you should watch carefully which methods you use when you do some long-running job. AsyncTask has a method `doInBackground` which gets called from a worker thread and other calls are made from the UI thread. If you're getting ANR, that means you do your job in the UI thread, which is wrong. You should do it in `doInBackground` method instead.

Check out [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [Painless Threading article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Answer (score 0):

Cody If I had to debug, I would wrap the entire doInBackground in try catch exception e and do Log.d(TAG,"doInBackground",e). Malcolm is correct that this should not result in an ANR message unless you are somehow blocking the UI thread.